# Error while selection "Team" in case layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, case, standard-objects

Every time I open a case and try to change the “Team” I'll get the error message.

[image]

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Case
2. Select “Team”

---

I believe this is not something we can solve ourselves, as it seems to be related to a standard component.

Regardless of the error, I believe you can edit the team or any other field in the meantime.

This problem comes up not when you specifically try to edit the Team on a case, but when you click any pencil icon in any field. But if you navigate to the standard record edit page this error doesn’t pop up. This leads me to believe the error comes not from the page layout, but rather from something else on the page (for example, the chatter feed).

I tried logging is as the another user, which has the profile Standard User, and the problem didn’t appear, so all users aren’t affected by this, and if we are lucky it’s only System Administrators.

Since this seems to be an issue related to a standard component.

How is it possible to resolve the issue without receiving this error message? Suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! *Firstly*, this sounds more like a statement written to management after researching an issue than it sounds like a question. I am assuming since you posted here that you are searching for help in overcoming the error? Just know that this is not an official Salesforce site and so posting here is *not* contacting Salesforce Support. *Secondly*, if you are looking here for any assistance, please edit your question to add the *exact* (copy/paste) error you are seeing.

Comment: Have I overlooked anything or where is the error message you're referring to? In addition to that, statements like "I believe you can edit..." would ideally be replaced by "You can edit...", if you could try?!

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick comment, it would be very good if i could get the necessary support or advice to solve the issue. I have already contacted SF support but they could not give me the necessary help due to Support Plan regulations. I have added a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: I don't think you're using standard functionality here. The "Message" of your screenshot refers to a component ("LWC") that uses a specific technology ("UI API"), which is not supported by an object ("EmailMessage") that is used by the component. Apparently the component is misconfigured or used in an unsupported context. I'm not sure what pencil icon you're referring to and who provided it to you. Do you use a package? What is this page made up of?